PowerShell Set-ACL issues -Unexpected error occurred: Exception calling ".ctor" with "5" argument(s): "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: identity"
I'm having issues with a script I'm writing to remotely modify file share permissions. I am trying to remove all domain user and group permissions, then add back group permissions that were created in an earlier portion of the script.
When I run the part to remove all domain user and group access line by line, it works exactly as I intend. It removes everything except SYSTEM and other local permissions. However, when I run the whole script, it removes ALL permissions (including SYSTEM), and errors out with this:
Unexpected error occurred: Exception calling ".ctor" with "5" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: identity"
Exception name: System.Management.Automation.RemoteException
Here is the entire code block in question:
    $Sesh = New-PSSession -ComputerName $I
    $Result = Invoke-Command -Session $Sesh -ArgumentList $FileShares -Scriptblock {
        param($FileShares)
        foreach ($F in $FileShares){
            $Share = $F.Name
            $Path = $F.Path
            $ACL = Get-ACL -Path $Path

            # Remove all domain user and group access
            if ($ACLsToRemove = $ACL.Access | ? {($_.IdentityReference -like "$Domain*") -and ($_.IsInherited -like "False")}) { 
                foreach ($A in $ACLsToRemove) {
                    $Identity = $A.IdentityReference
                    $ACL.RemoveAccessRuleAll($A)
                    Set-ACL -Path $Path -AclObject $ACL
                }
            }

            $InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
            $PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]"None"
            $AccessControl = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]"Allow"

            # Create and set ACL for Full Control
            # Set properties
            $Identity = (Get-ADGroup -Filter "(Name -like '$I*' -and Name -like '*$Share*' -and Name -like '*Full')").SamAccountName
            $FileSystemAccessRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"FullControl"
            # Create new rule
            $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList ($Identity,$FileSystemAccessRights,$InheritanceFlag,$PropagationFlag,$AccessControl)
            # Apply new rule
            $ACL.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
            Set-ACL -Path $Path -AclObject $ACL

            # Create and set ACL for Modify
            # Set properties
            $Identity = (Get-ADGroup -Filter "(Name -like '$I*' -and Name -like '*$Share*' -and Name -like '*Modify')").SamAccountName
            $FileSystemAccessRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Modify"
            # Create new rule
            $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList ($Identity,$FileSystemAccessRights,$InheritanceFlag,$PropagationFlag,$AccessControl)
            # Apply new rule
            $ACL.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
            Set-ACL -Path $Path -AclObject $ACL

            # Create and set ACL for Read and Execute
            # Set properties
            $Identity = (Get-ADGroup -Filter "(Name -like '$I*' -and Name -like '*$Share*' -and Name -like '*Read')").SamAccountName
            $FileSystemAccessRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"ReadAndExecute"
            # Create new rule
            $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList ($Identity,$FileSystemAccessRights,$InheritanceFlag,$PropagationFlag,$AccessControl)
            # Apply new rule
            $ACL.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
            Set-ACL -Path $Path -AclObject $ACL
        }
    }
    Remove-PSSession $Sesh

I tried running the above code block, expecting it to remove all domain user and group permissions on the file share, then assign group permissions to the file share.
Instead, it removes all NTFS permissions including local SYSTEM. And it doesn't add the new group permissions.

My guess is you're not getting anything with a filter for $identity like "(Name -like '$I*' -and Name -like '*$Share*' -and Name -like '*Full')".. Should your -and operators here maybe be -or ??? You should add a test if $identity actually is something and if it is not an array (in which case use a better filter again or just take the first element of that array)
